# Upgrading to jetty 9.4 replacing the HashSessionManager

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

After upgrading to jetty 9.4 I notice a ClassNotFoundException for `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager`.
I think I need to use a `FileSessionDataStore` but I don't see how that is suppose to be set on a `SessionHandler`.

The configuration I currently have is:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    ...
    <Set name="sessionHandler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
            <Arg> 
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager">
                    <Set name="storeDirectory">my/store/path</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

I don't see what I need to do, `SessionHandler` doesn't take a `SessionDataStore`, but a `SessionCache` can be set on it but it looks like the implementations of `SessionCache` want a `SessionHandler` in the constructor, I don't see how to do that in XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the jetty-9.4 session architecture, you have `SessionHandler` takes a `SessionCache`, which optionally takes a `SessionDataStore`.

See [`OneServletContextWithSession`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.7.v20170914/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneServletContextWithSession.java) for a programmatic example.

That example uses the `NullSessionDataStore`, but the principle is the same as the `FileSessionDataStore`, which is the replacement for the old `HashSessionManager` ability to store sessions to disk.

The Jetty Documentation contains information [on changes from previous versions of Jetty session management to the 9.4 style](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.7.v20170914/upgrading-jetty.html#_session_management).

If you follow links in the documentation, you'll also find detailed info on the new session architecture.

As the documentation explains, the easiest way to configure sessions in jetty-9.4 when running in the distribution is to enable the appropriate module. However, if you're running embedded, or you just want to set up session management for a particular webapp in xml, here's some example code of setting up the `FileSessionDataStore`:

```xml
<Get id="sh" name="sessionHandler">
    <Set name="sessionCache">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache">
          <Arg><Ref id="sh"/></Arg>
          <Set name="sessionDataStore">
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.FileSessionDataStore">
              <Set name="storeDir">/tmp/sessions</Set>
            </New>
          </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Get>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I think I worked it out, it is not pretty it ended up as:

```
<Set name="sessionHandler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
    </New>
</Set>

<Call name="getSessionHandler" id="sessionHandler" />

<Ref refid="sessionHandler">
    <Set name="SessionCache">    
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache">
            <Arg>
                <Ref refid="sessionHandler"/>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="SessionDataStore">
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.FileSessionDataStore">
                        <Set name="StoreDir">my/store/path</Set>
                </New>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Ref>
```

I followed the easier to read pure java example I found at http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.FileSessionDataStore

If this doesn't look correct to a Jetty expert I am happy to edit the answer so as not to mislead others.